# Looking for Elasticsearch updateByQuery syntax example (Node driver)

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

You have an Elasticsearch index with two docs:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "myType",
    "_id": "es1472002807930",
    "_source": {
      "animal": "turtle",
      "color": "green",
      "weight": 20,
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "myIndex",
    "_type": "myType",
    "_id": "es1472002809463",
    "_source": {
      "animal": "bear",
      "color": "brown"
      "weight": 400,
    }
  }
]
```

Later, you get this updated data about the bear:

```
{
  "color": "pink",
  "weight": 500,
  "diet": "omnivore",
}
```

So, you want to update the "color" and "weight" values of the bear, and add the "diet" key to the "bear" doc. You know there's only one doc with `"animal": "bear"` (but you don't know the _id):

Using the Nodejs driver, what updateByQuery syntax would update the "bear" doc with these new values?

**(NOTE: this question has been entirely edited to be more useful to the SO community!)**

Answer (score 10):

The answer was provided by Val in this other SO:

[How to update a document based on query using elasticsearch-js (or other means)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37177566/how-to-update-a-document-based-on-query-using-elasticsearch-js-or-other-means)

Here is the answer:

```
    var theScript = {
        "inline": "ctx._source.color = 'pink'; ctx._source.weight = 500; ctx._source.diet = 'omnivore';"
    }

    client.updateByQuery({ 
           index: myindex,
           type: mytype,
           body: { 
              "query": { "match": { "animal": "bear" } }, 
              "script": theScript
           }
        }, function(err, res) { 
            if (err) { 
               reportError(err) 
            } 
            cb(err, res)
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 8):

The other answer is missing the point since it doesn't have any script to carry out the update.

You need to do it like this:

```
POST /myIndex/myType/_update_by_query
{
  "query": { 
    "term": {
      "animal": "bear"
    }
  },
  "script": "ctx._source.color = 'green'"
}
```

Important notes:

- you need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.
- if you are using ES 2.3 or later, then the update-by-query feature is built-in
- if you are using ES 1.7.x or a former release you need to install the [update-by-query plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery)
- if you are using anything between ES 2.0 and 2.2, then you don't have any way to do this in one shot, you need to do it in two operations.

**UPDATE**

Your node.js code should look like this, you're missing the `body` parameter:

```
    client.updateByQuery({ 
           index: index,
           type: type,
           body: { 
              "query": { "match": { "animal": "bear" } }, 
              "script": { "inline": "ctx._source.color = 'pink'"}
           }
        }, function(err, res) { 
            if (err) { 
               reportError(err) 
            } 
            cb(err, res)
        }
    )
```

Comment: I have dynamic scripting enabled
I'm using ES 2.3
I'm using the Nodejs driver library

When I execute:

    client.updateByQuery({
            index: 'myIndex',
            type: 'myType',
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "animal": "bear"
                }
              },
              "script": "ctx._source.color = 'green'"

        }, function(err, res) {
            if (err) { reportError(err) }
        })


I get this error (in the following comment):

Comment: Ok, then it should work provided you have a compatible ES version (<=1.7 or >=2.3)

Comment: Strangely, that command creates a 3rd document in the index:

{
"_index": "myindex",
"_type": "mytype",
"_id": "_update_by_query",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"query": {
"match": {
"animal": "bear"
}
},
"script": "ctx._source.color = 'green'"
}
},

Comment: Which exact version of ES are you using ? 2.3.2 or 2.3.3 ?

Comment: Ah, the version is 2.2.0. I will try upgrading. Also, thanks so much for your help, and I apologize for the formatting, this looks better:

https://kobra.io/#/e/-KPuwAytjSUkU5K_BbFv

Comment: Great to hear it was just a version issue. Let us know!

Answer (score 3):

For elasticsearch 7.4 you could use

```
await client.updateByQuery({
  index: "indexName",
  body: {
    query: {
      match: { fieldName: "valueSearched" }
    },
    script: {
      source: "ctx._source.fieldName = params.newValue",
      lang: 'painless',
      params: {
        newValue: "newValue"
      }
    }
  }
});
```