# How to use client.updateByQuery elasticsearch library for nodejs?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am currently using elastic search for the datebase in a nodejs/express application. Currently, there is an index called titles which stores information about movie titles and meta data about it. Looking at the client's requests, they want to be able to change the fields in all documents in a certain index and type. 
I was referring to the documentation for the elasticsearch library for node.js and more specifically the method client.updateByQuery method. There isnt an example on how to use it. Can someone show me how one would update all the documents in a certain index where a field matches a query?

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113370/looking-for-elasticsearch-updatebyquery-syntax-example-node-driver/39114233#39114233

Comment: @Val Which language is the script in? Could you link me to documentation on how to further manipulate values and fields in documents using said language?

Comment: At the time it was Groovy, but now in ES 5 a new scripting language called Painless is available. more info at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html